# Capitals after a quotation when describing the quotation as having been heard, not said

Tags: grammar, capitalization

> "Yes?" she asked.

Here, `she` has no capital, because `"Yes?"` is an element of the same sentence, which describes what is happening said element.

> "Noooo!" He fell to his knees.

Here, `He` is capitalized, because it's the start of a new sentence, describing what happened after the implicit "[whoever] said" of the quotation.

OK, but is the following correct?

> "Why?" she heard him ask.

The reason I'm not 100% sure is that the part after the quote is not describing him asking, but instead describing her hearing him.

If that's wrong, then fixing it by capitalizing `she` would be awkward, because then the separate sentence might imply that there's a second thing being asked.  So then you'd have to go further to refer back to the quote as `this`, but that's also awkward:

> "Why?"  She heard him ask this.

You would probably want add something to make it worth using `heard` over `said` in the first place, making it something like:

> "Why?"  She heard him ask *this*, but then everything went black.
>
> "Why?"  She *heard* him ask this.  I could tell by the puzzled look it elicited from her.

Comment: I'd have no problems with ' "Why?" she heard him ask.' We wouldn't baulk at '... she heard him ask/shout "Why?" '. And with the re-ordering, the meaning remains clear, and a period wouldn't enhance clarity (as you say, probably the opposite). Punctuation is here to help, not enslave and terrorise. / You're right about awkwardness being best avoided, and about the difference padding makes here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question.

> > "Yes?" she asked.
>
> Here, *she* has no capital, because *"Yes?"* is an element of the same sentence, which describes what is happening said element.

That is, *"Yes?"* is the object of *asked.*

In your queried sentence, it's much the same:

> > "Why?" she heard him ask.
>
> The reason I'm not 100% sure is that the part after the quote is not describing him asking, but instead describing her hearing him.

Re-arrange, and *Why* is again the object of *ask.* It's all part of the same sentence.